# Помогите загрузить в сцену three.js файл формата .pial, построенный FreeSurfer'ом

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Хочу загрузить в сцену Three.js файл lh.pial(меш коры мозга) построенный FreeSurfer'ом, используя [loaders.freesurfer.js](https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/blob/d6245abb86f0929eda27ae02b5dcd5dc1b49a374/src/loaders/loaders.freesurfer.js#L13).
Вот мой код:

```
const sizes = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webgl");

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Freesurfer
const freeSurferLoader = new THREE.FreeSurferLoader();

const brain = freeSurferLoader.load("lh.pial", function (geometry) {
  console.log(geometry);

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "red" });

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);
});

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height);
camera.position.z = 3;
camera.lookAt(mesh.position);
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas,
});

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Но вылетает ошибка **"Uncaught ReferenceError: mesh is not defined"**, почему mesh создается но не добавляется в сцену?

Comment: Вы же объявляете `mesh` в callback'е лоудера, а `camera.lookAt(mesh.position);` здесь пытаетесь сослаться на объект, который еще не существует и объявлен в блочной области.

Comment: Если верить исходному коду загрузчика - там используется тип геометрии `THREE.Geometry()`, что может вызвать проблемы для версий фреймворка 125+, так как этот тип геометрии был удален, теперь есть только `THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Вынес объявление `mesh` из callback теперь вижу ошибку: **Cannot read property 'isBufferGeometry' of null**

Comment: По версии я использую старую что бы поддерживала `THREE.Geometry()`